# WP Show more than one post from selected category

Tags: php, wordpress

On my category page, there's a list of all categories to select from. Once you select a category, all posts with that category will show. At the moment only one post is showing as the result. I want to show all posts (up to 10 max) that are in the selected category. Code is below. How do I get it to show up to 10 posts per category?

```
<?php if (!have_posts()) : ?>
<div class="alert">
  <?php _e('Sorry, no results were found.', 'roots'); ?>
</div>
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php $i = 0; ?>

<?php 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    $i++;  
?>

<article class="<?php $allClasses = get_post_class(); foreach   ($allClasses as $class) { echo $class . " "; } if($i&1) { echo 'odd';} else {echo 'even';}; ?> block clearfix">
    <?php get_template_part('templates/content-category', get_post_format()); ?>
 </article>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got to work by removing this:

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>


 <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $i++;  ?>

  <article class="<?php $allClasses = get_post_class(); foreach ($allClasses as $class) { echo $class . " "; } if($i&1) { echo 'odd';} else {echo 'even';};  ?> block clearfix">
  <?php get_template_part('templates/content-category', get_post_format()); ?>
   </article>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
```

and replacing it with this:

```
 <?php query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=-10' );?>
 <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
 <article class="block clearfix">
 <?php   get_template_part('templates/contentcategory',                       
  get_post_format()); ?>
  </article>
  <br />
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```